# How to hide EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD in settings.py file?

Tags: python, django, passwords

So, I have an application written with Django and it has a contact page, from where users can send mail using gmail's smtp. For this functionality in settings.py file I wrote `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my-own-password'`, and I'm gonna deploy my site on github.io. So, I must hide or encrypt password. What can I do with that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things about your question:

1. You cannot deploy Django app on github pages because they serve only static files. Check e.g. Heroku, it's quite easy to deploy Django there.
2. The most common practice to hide passwords and secret keys is to use environmental variables. Generally, you have to set a variable in bash e.g. `export EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=my-own-password` and then you can use `os` python module to retrieve it:

```py
import os

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
```

Useful video tutorials:

- [Python Django Tutorial: Deploying Your Application (Option #2) - Deploy using Heroku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DI_7Zja8Zc)
- [Python Quick Tip: Hiding Passwords and Secret Keys in Environment Variables (Mac & Linux)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iWhQWVXosU)

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy a django application on github pages as described here : https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-is-github-pages.

If you want to upload you code on github and you don't want to share your password you can put it in another file and add this file to your `.gitignore`

Comment: What a bad news. Then is there any free service like github pages ? @louisld

Comment: I found this with a quick search on the Internet : https://www.pythonanywhere.com/. But you can use a Amazon Web Service which is free for one year.

Answer (score 0):

### You can do this by using environment variables as following:

1. install `python-decouple`

   ```
   pip install django-decouple
   ```
2. Create file `.env` next to `settings.py` file
3. Cut `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-password'` in `settings.py` file and put it in `.env` file
4. In `settings.py` file:

   - Import `from decouple import config`
   - Then, in the same line you cut before insert `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")`
5. Once you have made these changes, be sure to add the `.env` file to your `.gitignore` file so that it is not committed to your version control system.